# I am making a form to obtain the data from the web

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-apps-script, web-applications

I am trying to make a form to obtain data from the web, the case is I have it like this but it does not collect any data I do not know if I have something wrong.

This would be the code.gs file:

```js
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index')
  .evaluate()
  .setTitle('Test');
}

function userClicked(userInfo) {
  Logger.log(userInfo.firstname);
  Logger.log(userInfo.lastname);
  Logger.log(userInfo.app);
}

function include(File) {
  let html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(File).getContent();
  return html;
  }
```

This is the IndexJS.html:

```html
<script>
  document.getElementById('btn').addEventListene('click', function( event ) {
    let userInfo = {};
    event.preventDefault();
    userInfo.firstName = document.getElementById('fn').value;
    userInfo.lastname = document.getElementById('ln').value;
    userInfo.app = document.getElementById('app').value;
    google.script.run.userClicked( userInfo );
  });
</script>
```

And this is the form, the Index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <?!= include("IndexCSS")?>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hola</h1>
      <form>
        <div class="form-row">
          <label>FirstName:</label><input type="text" id="fn">
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
          <label>LastName:</label><input type="text" id="ln">
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
          <label>Apps:</label>
          <select id="app">
            <option>Google Sheet</option> <option>Excel</option> <option>Numbers</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row"> <button id="btn">Send</button> </div>
      </form>
    <?!=include("IndexJS")?>
  </body>  
   
</html>
```

I can't get any data in the execution history

Comment: Do you get an error in the web browser developer tools?

Comment: `ddEventListene` is spelled wrong

Comment: If you give all of the inputs the name attribute and then pass this.parentNode to the function all the names become properties of the object passed to the function.

Answer (score 0):

As @Cooper mentions you have a typo in your Index.js file.

The event listener is not added because the instruction `addEventListener` is spelled wrong: "addEventListene".

Change it and it will work.